# How to generalize two classes

Tags: c#, .net, generics, dispose, idisposable

How I can combine `class A` and `class B` into for example single generic class

```
public interface IA { }
public interface IB { }

public class A : IA, IDisposable
{
    public void Clear()
    {
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            //logic
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}

public class B : IB, IDisposable
{
    public void Detach()
    {
    }
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
          //logic
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}

public class BClearIfFail : B
{
    private readonly Func<bool> _isFailed;

    public BClearIfFail(Func<bool> isFailed)
    {
        _isFailed = isFailed;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool dispose)
    {
        if (dispose)
        {
            if (_isFailed())
            {
               Detach();
               return;
            }
        }

        base.Dispose(dispose);
    }
}

public class AClearIfFail : A
{
    private readonly Func<bool> _isFailed;

    public AClearIfFail(Func<bool> isFailed)
    {
        _isFailed = isFailed;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool dispose)
    {
        if (dispose)
        {
            if (_isFailed())
            {
                Clear();
                return;
            }
        }

        base.Dispose(dispose);
    }
}
```

In other words I need something like this:

```
//not for compile =)
public class Single<T> : T where T : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Func<bool> _whenSkip;
    private readonly Action _howToSkip;

    public Single(Func<bool> whenSkip, Action howToSkip)
    {
        _whenSkip = whenSkip;
        _howToSkip = howToSkip;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_whenSkip())
        {
            Log.Message1(Resources.LogCleanupOfResourcesWillBeSkipped);
            _howToSkip();
            return;
        }

        T.Dispose();
    }
}
```

How I want to use this class in my code:

```
public static class MyFactory<T>
{
    public static T Create(bool skipCleanUp, Func<bool> isFailed, Action howToSkip)
    {
        return skipCleanUp ? new Single<T>(isFailed, howToSkip) : new T();
    }
}
```

And I try to explain context:

```
public interface IUndoStack
{
    void Push(Action action);
}

public class UndoStack : IUndoStack, IDisposable
{
    private readonly Stack<Action> _undo = new Stack<Action>();

    public UndoStack()
    {
    }

    public void Push(Action action)
    {
        _undo.Push(action);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _undo.Clear();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool dispose)
    {
        if (dispose)
        {
            foreach (var action in _undo)
            {
                try
                {
                    action.Call();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.Exception(e);
                }
            }
            _undo.Clear();
        }
    }
}

//context

private void RestoreDatabase()
{
    UndoStack undoStack = null;

    try
    {
        undoStack = new UndoStack();
        undoStack.Add(DeleteFiles())
        CopyFiles(undoStack);
        undoStack.Clear();
    }
    catch when(SkipCleanUpIfFail)
    {
        //Log
        undoStack?.Clear();
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        undoStack?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: so if i understand this right, you want to have some sort of wrapper that suppresses the dispose implementation of the original object under certain conditions and use some alternative implementation instead?

Comment: you are right =)

Comment: This doesn't seem like a proper use of the Dispose pattern. Maybe you can tell us what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: Also if the return T needs only to be disposable you should return the IDisposable rather them type T.

Comment: I need return T because of specific methods

Comment: @decPL I try to achieve not creating a lot of similar classes like BClearIfFail , AClearIfFail with the same functionality

Comment: There is something off with your implementation. When you come across design conundrums like this, it's usually a code smell. You shouldn't be "skipping" disposing in this manner. Think about who owns the dependencies and dispose them where you should.

Comment: @isxaker Well that explains everything /s I have no idea what BClearIfFail is and I can't honestly even guess from it's name. Some context? What you're trying to achieve, not how?

Comment: @decPL Ok. One of my class looks like a UndoStack. I ususally add there what I have to undo in case an exception will be thrown. Imagine that I'm doing something which takes a lot of time (copying 1000 files and requred more than 10 GB) and in the middle of that process an exception has been thrown. I need to remove(what I do in Dispose()) all files which has been already copied. But if I have to keep all copied files. I need skip Dispose().

Comment: some context has been added

Comment: So I need to come back to what I've said earlier - that is not what the Dispose pattern is intended (or IMHO should be used) for. Design your own methods for this - then you're no longer limited by `Dispose()` not taking any parameters.

Comment: There's no reason to call `GC.SuppressFinalize(this);` if you don't have a finalizer.  There's also no need to have your `Dispose` method accept a boolean unless you plan to have both managed and unmanaged things to dispose.  You're only ever disposing of managed things.

Comment: I know this stuff, but this class is used more than 1000 places so I don't have any desire to change them all. And what GC.SuppressFinalize(this); it's just a our team rules =)